I can't use Exact Alarm for flutter local notification
Currently, I am trying to display a notification in my app using flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.2.
The feature I am trying to implement in my app is to display a notification so that the user can use the app again the next day or later after opening the app today. At this time, the notification time is the time when the app was previously opened.
I have already written the code for the scheduled notification and tested it locally. If I add the permission below to the AndroidManifest.xml file, the notification works well.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
However, when I try to upload the app to the Google Play Store, I get the following error message and cannot publish it.
Publishing failed :|
Google Play failed to upload artefacts. You must let us know whether your app uses any exact alarm permissions: {
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "You must let us know whether your app uses any exact alarm permissions",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
What should I do to resolve this issue?
I tried to display a notification without using the Exact Alarm permission, but it didn't work.

This should help;

If you app is not a clock or an alarm, you may not be allowed to use

in your manifest. To handle the PlatformException you can using this
androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.inexactAllowWhileIdle,
instead of androidScheduleMode:
AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78552200/3368257
